# Laravel 4 - Eloquent doesn't bind parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

While trying to add a new row to a database table, I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`testas`.`translations`, CONSTRAINT `translations_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`labelId`) REFERENCES `label` (`id`)) (SQL: update `translations` set
>   `labelId` = where `id` = 103)

As you can see, it doesn't bind a parameter to `labelId`. What's causing this?

EDIT:

```
$labelKey = Label::max('key') + 1;
$label = new Label(array('key' => $labelKey));
$label->save(); //the label gets saved in the labels table


$title = new Translation(array('phrase' => $input['title']));

$title->language()->associate($language);
$title->label()->associate($label);

$title->save(); //this part is failing
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippet.

Comment: It's odd that you get an update-query for the translation because your code looks like you're creating a new translation.

Comment: @doitmyway, make sure your `$label` contains a `Label` model and `$language` variable contains proper data.

Comment: They do, I've already debugged it.